# Inline AMPscript with personalisation string not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, inline

I want to use inline AMPscript with a personalisation string that should now the content if the field is not empty otherwise the block should not be shown. This does not work (the content is still showing if the field in the DE is empty):

`%%=IIF(NOT EMPTY(property_id), "%%Object_title_1%%", "")=%%`

However it works if I use text only (this is shown or not shown based on the attribute being empty or not):

`%%=IIF(NOT EMPTY(property_id), "Lorem ipsum", "")=%%`

Do you have any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can set a variable by [AttributeValue](https://ampscript.guide/attributevalue/) function to render the value and then put it in the inline AMPscript. Try this:

```
%%[
  set @Object_title_1 = AttributeValue("Object_title_1")
]%%

%%=IIF(NOT EMPTY(property_id), @Object_title_1, "")=%%
```

Answer (score 1):

That’s because you put the personalization string in quotation marks, which makes it a literal string. Try this:

```
%%=IIF(NOT EMPTY(property_id),Object_title_1,"")=%%
```